# How to add a certain word before the names of methods in Javascript?

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace, macro, vscode

I am working with react. First I had a component with state I created methods and all that. Now I want to convert it into stateless component. I have add the word `function` before each method name.

This is my file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Form = ({ sumbitBtn, onSubmit, inputs, id }) => {
   onSubmit() {
   }
   renderInputs() {
   }
   sendErrors(errors) {
   }
   return (
       ...
   );
};
```

Now I have tried to do it two ways but neither of them worked for me.

#### Using regular expression

I used the each of the following commands.

```
:%s/\w+\(\w*\)/function &/g
:%s/\w+\(\w*\)/function \0/g
:%s/(\w+\(\w*\))/function \1/g
```

But unfortunately the names of methods are showing rather its showing like `function &`, `function \0`.

#### Using macros

Another idea that came into my mind was that I could use a macro. Which have steps but I was stuck in one of the step which is finding the next method using regular expression and jumping to it.

My question is that how can we do this using both of the ways.

**Note:** the above file is just example file. The original file contains line breaks, comments between the methods.

**Note:** I am using the vim extension on vscode.

The result I want to get is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Form = ({ sumbitBtn, onSubmit, inputs, id }) => {
   function onSubmit() {
   }
   function renderInputs() {
   }
   function sendErrors(errors) {
   }
   return (
       ...
   );
};
```

Comment: Can you verify version? Whether or not compatible is set? Im surprised & and \0 didnt work...

Comment: I think this might explain why this isn't working for you: *"I am using the vim extension on vscode"*. Unfortunately, I can't really tell how close to actual Vim the Vim extension in VS Code is, so not sure how much of Vim features it supports... Perhaps take a look into how *native* search/replace works in VS Code, to see whether that can work in your case or not...

Comment: @filbranden I completely missed that. Has to be the issue.

Comment: Note that this question seems pretty off topic to me according to [our help center](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Seconded. Reminds me of questions asked about Intellij IdeaVim plugin. If such a vim standin is being used but the question only involves vim functionality, generically, it's kosher, otherwise off topic...is my recollection.

Comment: @BLayer I have figured out the solution should I answer my question or just delete it?

Comment: Hi. Is the answer something specific to "vim extension on vscode"? If so then we'll probably close the question (we don't usually delete them) so probably not worth the effort to write an answer.

Comment: @BLayer No its not specific to "vscode extension". I later tested on vim and it didn't worked. But now I found the way to do that. So should "answer my own question" or not?

Comment: If it's a problem that other people might face with the normal vim offerings then, yes, you can write an answer.

Comment: for VSCode, use the vscode-neovim extension. The normal vim extension sucks; unfortunately it's heavily promoted even though it has around less than half of vim's features implemented, so most people end up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I have tested the above process in vim(not it vscode extension). It didn't worked so the answer is for general vim.

#### Using Regular expressions

The solution to the first problem is to use "very magic" mode of regex. In very magic mode the characters except `a-zA-Z0-9` and  `_`  have a special meaning. You can enable very magic mode by putting `\v` in start of regex.

```
:%s/\v(\w+\(\w*\))/function \1/g
    ^^
```

If you don't want to put \v each time check out [In vim, is there a way to set “very magic” permanently and globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760444/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-set-very-magic-permanently-and-globally)

#### Using macros

In the following steps you can record the macro.

- press `qm` to start recording macro.
- Go the start of the line using `^`
- Use `i` to enter insert mode and enter `function`
- Go the normal mode.
- Use `/\v(\w+\(\w*\))` to search for next method.
- Press `n` to go the next method. Press `q` to complete recording macro.

Go the first method and use `n@m` where `n` is total number of methods to which you want add `function`

Comment: For answering the question rather than kvetching plus 1